# cppcheck write xml to output file and "understandable" results to the console

Tags: continuous-integration, command-line-interface, static-analysis, cppcheck

Using cppcheck (1.86-r0), the following prints the results to an xml file. However, the console output stays completely empty.

`cppcheck --quiet --error-exitcode=1 --xml --xml-version=2 --output-file=CPPCheckReport.xml --inline-suppr --enable=warning ./src`

Additionally Specifying a template (adding `--template=vs` to above command) does not work, the output-file takes precedence here

How can I store the xml (which I later [convert into JUnit](https://github.com/johnthagen/cppcheck-junit)) and output meaningful messages in the console (which I need for a better understanding of my CI job)?

Comment: @Daniel Marjamäki is this currently possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `cppcheck` does this, but you may be able to get meaningful messages by processing the XML output file. For example, something like this:

```
cppcheck --all-your-options-from-above
grep -E '<location ' CPPCheckReport.xml | sed 's/^ *//'
```

The `grep` above extracts all the location lines for errors found, and the `sed` just removes leading spaces. Maybe other processing might be useful, depending on what you consider "meaningful messages".

The above example runs `cppcheck` and then processes the output file. If `cppcheck` is slow, you might prefer to send `cppcheck` output to stderr instead of an output file, use `tee` to send it to the output file, and then pipe the output directly into `grep`. That way, you could see errors as they are produced.